# Open Video From Intent Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I can't run an intent to play a video from a folder saved in external storage specifically in DCMI/subdirectory.

Using this code I get the error:

```
'file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/subdirectory/video-213102-113126.mp4 exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()'

Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(file_path);
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionView);
intent.SetDataAndType(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file), "video/mp4");
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent);
```

Reading I saw that I have to use a Fileprovider so I tried with this code:

```
Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(file_path);            
Android.Net.Uri photoURI = AndroidX.Core.Content.FileProvider.GetUriForFile(Android.App.Application.Context, Android.App.Application.Context.PackageName + ".provider", file);
Android.Content.Intent intent = new Android.Content.Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionView);
intent.SetDataAndType(photoURI, "video/*");
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent);
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<application android:label="MYAPP.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" />
        
        <activity android:name=".CameraActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" />

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
        
    </application>
```

provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

In debugging I see that the file variable is /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/subdirectory/video-213703-033712.mp4}

and photoURI is {content://com.companyname.myapp.provider/external_files/DCIM/subdirectory/video-213703-033712.mp4}

Intent is launched but the video is not played probably because it does not find the file in the path

Comment: Could  you please the full error log about this problem? If it is convinient for you, could you please post a basic demo to github or onedriver so that we can test on our side?

Comment: I don't see any debugging errors.
The intent is launched, the popup appears to choose the application to open the video but once chosen the application says it cannot find the file and therefore cannot be played.

Comment: If it is convinient for you, could you please post a basic demo to github or onedriver so that we can test on our side?

Comment: Here: https://github.com/lorismich/myapp

Comment: Also tried in a samsung but it doesn't work

Comment: There are many errors. You should have uploaded less code files, I couldn't run properly on my Android device.

Comment: Where do you find errors? My visual studio builds it successfully

Comment: Sorry  for late response.  You can use  [Xamarin.Essentials: Media Picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/media-picker?tabs=android) to achieve this function .